# How to access the google spreadsheet data in my Vue.js project using Axios and Google spreadsheet API?

Tags: vue.js, google-sheets, axios, google-sheets-api

I am working on a project which requires to show the data from the google spreadsheet. I have used Vue library for JS coding.

I want to use Axios API because I am already using it in my code for some more purposes.

First of all. is it possible to do with Axios?

and if yes then please suggest some blogs or links which help me to do this task?

Comment: Do you mean this [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md)?

Comment: Yes. You got it right..........

Comment: You might want to show what you did after reading the docs. Looks like you can make HTTP requests using that. Not sure if they allow reading without the API key. Check the Google Spreadsheet API as well.